# In 'declare -p' output, what do the '--' lines mean?

Tags: bash, declare

Edit: This is not a duplicate, at least not for the referenced question. That question is referring to the use of '--' to stop further processing of options from the command line. My question has to do with the output of the declare builtin.

---

I accidentally `declare`d a variable in a script with both `-l` and `-u` but there was no error.

```
declare -lu myvar='TestString'
echo "myvar: $myvar"
```

Which gives `myvar: TestString` If I add `declare -p` I get a declare with a double dash (`--`).

```
declare -lu myvar='TestString'
declare -p myvar
echo "myvar: $myvar"
```

Which gives

```
declare -- myvar="TestString"
myvar: TestString
```

Out of curiosity, I ran `declare -p | grep 'declare --'` from the command line and got quite a few variables that matched. Some are from my setup, but some are from bash itself.

```
declare -- BASH="/bin/bash"
declare -- BASH_ARGV0
declare -- BASH_COMMAND
declare -- BASH_SUBSHELL
declare -- BASH_VERSION="5.0.7(1)-release"
declare -- COLUMNS="211"
declare -- COMPLETION_UTIL=" pmbin pmcat pmchkver pmcore pmcost pmdoc pmedit pminfo pmless pmlines pmlist pmman pmpath pmstripper pmuninst pmversion pmxs podpath"
declare -- COMP_WORDBREAKS
declare -- CU="podpath"
declare -- DZIL=""
declare -- EPOCHREALTIME
declare -- EPOCHSECONDS
declare -- HISTCONTROL="erasedups:ignoreboth"
declare -- HISTFILE="/home/harleypig/.bash_history"
declare -- HISTFILESIZE="100000"
declare -- HISTIGNORE="&:[ ]*:exit:ls:bg:fg:history:clear"
declare -- HISTSIZE="500000"
declare -- HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
declare -- HOSTNAME="sweetums"
declare -- HOSTTYPE="x86_64"
declare -- IFS=" 
declare -- LINES="55"
declare -- MACHTYPE="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
declare -- OPTERR="1"
declare -- OSTYPE="linux-gnu"
declare -- POD=""
declare -- PROMPT_COMMAND="_update_prompt"
declare -- PS1="\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]\\n\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]REBOOT - Current: 5.0.13-arch1-1-ARCH Latest: 5.1.2-arch1-1-ARCH\\nPacman Last Updated: 23h 20m\\n\\001\\002\\001\\002\\u\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]@\\001\\002\\001\\002\\h\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]: /home/harleypig\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]\\n\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\001\\002:)\\001\\002\\001\\002\\] \$ "
declare -- PS2="> "
declare -- PS4="+ "
declare -- SECONDS
declare -- _="vim"
declare -- _backup_glob="@(#*#|*@(~|.@(bak|orig|rej|swp|dpkg*|rpm@(orig|new|save))))"
declare -- circled_digits="⓪①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳"
declare -- color_off="\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]"
declare -- exit_status="\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\001\\002:)\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]"
declare -- filename="/tmp/bash-template-D8fdfMZ"
declare -- hostname="\\001\\002\\001\\002\\h\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]"
declare -- lesspipe=""
declare -- nvm_init="/usr/share/nvm/init-nvm.sh"
declare -- pacman_status="Pacman Last Updated: 23h 20m"
declare -- prompt_color="\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]"
declare -- system_reboot="REBOOT - Current: 5.0.13-arch1-1-ARCH Latest: 5.1.2-arch1-1-ARCH"
declare -- user="\\001\\002\\001\\002\\u\\[\\001\\002\\001\\002\\]"
declare -- vim_bundles=".vim/bundle"
```

So, what does the '--' mean in the declare output?

I've read the bash manual through a number of times but I'm not seeing where this explanation might be.

Comment: `--` means simply that there are no flags or modifiers; you have a simple, standard, non-exported, default-string-type shell variable (not flagged an integer, not flagged read-only, etc etc). It's the *absence* of any changes in state.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Is this documented anywhere? I know you're correct obviously, although didn't see it anywhere in the documentation (or I couldn't find it). Thanks!

Comment: Guideline #10 in the [POSIX Utility Argument Syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)

Comment: @thatotherguy: Awesome, thank you!

Comment: Ok, so 'somevar=42' is functionally identical to 'declare somevar=42'? And those variables, at least the ones I know are mine, that are showing up in the output from the command line mean that I haven't been as neat as I should be in some of my startup files. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[man 1 bash](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

> ```
> declare [-aAfFgilnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
> ...
> When -p is supplied without name arguments, it will display the 
> attributes and values of all variables having the attributes specified 
> by the additional options. If no other options are supplied with -p, 
> declare will display the attributes and values of all shell variables. 
> ...
> ```

Your question says "I ran `declare -p | grep 'declare --'` ..." which will return the beginning line of every normal shell varaible declaration as they are formatted as `"declare -- ..."` by `declare -p` itself in the absence of any special declaration, e.g. `-i`, etc...

Comment: I'm not using '--', it's showing up when running `declare -p`. Charles Duffey and 'that other guy' have the answer I think. The section of the man page you quote does not state that '--' will be shown when no attributes are associated with a variable.

Comment: @harleypig the `--` is the default formatting that `declare` uses in its output. My answer explains that regardless whether you call `declare -p` or `declare -p --` the output will be identical. Your question says "I ran `declare -p | grep 'declare --'` ..." which will return the first line of every declaration as they are formatted as `declare --` by `declare -p` itself. (I did misread where your `'--'` was but it makes no difference to the answer)

Comment: Yes, I understood that `declare -p` and `declare -p --` gives the same output. I used grep to only show the declarations that were showing 'declare --', which is what I wasn't understanding. And the bash documentation doesn't clearly explain, by text or example, what this output means. I now understand that `somevar=42`, `declare somevar=42` and `declare -- somevar=42` are functionally identical and all will show the latter on `declare -p`. The text you referenced only makes sense to me now that I know what this means. The text in the manual could use some clarification I think.